# call of overloaded function is ambiguous using srand(time(0))?

Tags: c++

i have used srand(time(0)) in my program to generate random numbers ,the problem is my compiler shows an error that call of overloaded 'srand(time_t)' is ambiguous.i don't know what have i done wrong.
please help. i wanted to generate random numbers to be used in my minesweeper program , but it is giving this error. normally in any  other program where i am simply outputting the value it works okay , but in  this  case i am initializing the random value to a variable. i don't know what to do

Comment: `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));`

Comment: @ikh that did not work

Answer (score 1):

It means you have a non-standard overload of `srand` declared somewhere for some reason.

Either seek and destroy the rogue overload; or specify `std::srand` (if your standard library implementation isn't at fault); or convert the argument type to `unsigned int` to unambiguously choose the standard one.

Also, have a look at the new(ish) C++ random number library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random. It's a bit more complicated, but much more flexible, and without the evil of global state.

Comment: what do you mean by seeking and destroying the rogue overload ,using unsigned did not work

Comment: @avz2611: I mean finding where the non-standard overload is declared, and getting rid of it. The error message should tell you where all the overloads are declared. Assuming you're including the correct header (`<cstdlib>`), and your standard library implementation isn't broken, then either specifying `std::` or converting to `unsigned int` should work.

Comment: @avz2611 compile it with the clang compiler (if possible) it will tell you where your overloads are and why they couldn't be used.